# What causes Visual Studio To Change Control Names?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

In one project, the names of my GUI controls are being changed at compile time.

Say, for example, I have a Label control named **lblRow0Col1".

I noticed my code was failing to find the control by name:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls ' .Find("Label*", False)
        If ctrl.Name = "lblRow0Col1" Then
            ctrl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So, I stepped through that routine and found the control I needed had been renamed to what looks like a GUI string.

```
lbl.Name = "07178f89-6fdd-47c7-9f84-d4d661df7554"
```

[image: screenshot]

I created a test project to see what was going on, but this is not happening in the test project.

Is there a VS setting that tells the compiler to scramble the control names?

How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: Never heard of something like this. Are you sure that there is no error in your code? I mean, the Name property is writable at runtime so it is possible to change it in someway using your own code but not by VS.

Comment: I think I'm going to try rebooting my PC. That method was working before, so perhaps something got crossed in memory. BRB....

Comment: No, that didn't do it. There don't seem to be any errors. The GUI looking text only appears when the project is running under Visual Studio.

Comment: I would do a global search for `lbl.Name` to get every place where this label/property is used. By the way, what kind of application we are talking about here? WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF ?

Comment: It is a WinForm app.

Comment: Added that tag just now.

Comment: Do you have any Visual Studio extensions installed, such as Resharper? Any third-party controls used on your forms?

Comment: There are 4 extensions installed. 1) [ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36053), 2) [NuGet Package Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c), 3) [VS2012 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05), and 4) [VS Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687).

Comment: Come to think of it, the Color Theme Editor is fairly new. Hmmm....

Comment: I disabled the color theme and restarted. That didn't fix it. It just seems to be happening in this project, too.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your problem, but what is the reason behind not simply using `If ctrl Is lblRow0Col1` ?

Comment: Hey Helrich. There is a matrix of about 50 controls, all named according to their row and column. I though it would be a nice, mathematical way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I’ve been looking at the code for that routine that populates a "details view" screen.

Before, I was filling the detail screen as soon as the Inventory Item variable changed.

I got to thinking that people rarely view the details screen, so why not just populate it after the screen was displayed? I had an event for “after displayed”, so I moved it there.

Well, I just moved it back ...and the odd behavior went away.

I don’t know what the issue was that caused that to happen, though.

The Label controls should have already been generated, but it acts like they were not until the tab screen they were on was selected.

So, there's an answer, but I'd rather someone explain to me what I did wrong.